# Does Visual Studio 2008 utilitize Windows Search for "Find in Files"

Tags: visual-studio

or any of the other search options?

I usually disable all background indexing on my dev machines, but Find in Files feels slower on my latest dev machine when Windows Search is disabled, and I wonder why. I am unable to find any references to whether or not VS can leverage an existing Widows Search index for the files it is searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it does, no (and to my knowledge, it never has).

You could check out [Entrian Source Search](http://entrian.com/source-search/), which is an addin that gives you fast searching of Visual Studio code.  It builds a full text index, like Windows Search does.  (Full disclosure: I'm the author.)

Comment: Thanks for your insight!
Too bad MS haven't used this opportunity to enhance VS, but great that you have. :-)